# PHP in HTML(accessing $_POST data)

Tags: php, html, post

kalkulaator.php

```
<form method="post" action="arvutus.php">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

arvutus.php

```
$value = $value-($value*0.04-($value*0.04-144)*0.21);
echo "Result is " . $_POST["value"] . "";
```

How can I make these calculation with value ?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, PHP (like most programming languages) uses a decimal point, not a comma, so you'll need to fix that.

Second, you are not using the input variable correctly.

Third, your math can be simplified.

Try this:

```
$input = floatval($_POST['value']);
$result = $input*0.9516 - 30.24;
echo "Result is ".$result;
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine. Have a click :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = $_POST["value"];
$result = $value-($value * 0.04 - ($value * 0.04-144) * 0.21);
echo "Result is $result";
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors in the above code.

1) Floating point numbers use . (dot) and not a comma. Like this 1.04
2) $_POST is the array that contains all the post variables that came from the form to the script not the other way arround

You need

```
$value=$_POST['value'];
$result = $value-($value*0.04-($value*0.04-144)*0.21);
echo "Result is $result";
```